# Detecting a QR code in Kotlin (Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, qr-code, detection

I come to you after hours of desperation looking for a solution, spoiler: I haven't found it.
Let me explain, in my company, I'm in charge of developing a company that will simplify the work of technicians by scanning a QR Code. I've developed a camera display and zoom/unzoom functions with no problem. The tricky part is detecting the QR Code.
I don't even have any errors, just the classic camera display. Once, by chance, it put me QR code detected, but I've never managed to get it to work again.
I'm sure there's permission for the camera because I give it as soon as I open the app (and I have the camera).
Alert dialogs are useful for debugging, but they don't appear at all, any more than when I tried with Toasts... I think there really is a detection problem.

I used two libraries.
First :
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
And when I saw that detection was not working well or not at all, I tried :
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.1.1'
And it doesn't work any better, so for me the problem comes from the listener, or detection rather than the library.
With this problem I've even managed to reach the limits of GPT-4, which tells me that this QR code (https://t3.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcSh-wrQu254qFaRcoYktJ5QmUhmuUedlbeMaQeaozAVD4lh4ICsGdBNubZ8UlMvWjKC) isn't of good enough quality / not visible, even though my camera detects it without a problem.

```
package com.example.tekanalyzer

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.Camera
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.doOnLayout
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

class QRCodeScannerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleOwner {

    private lateinit var viewFinder: PreviewView
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private lateinit var scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector
    private lateinit var gestureDetector: GestureDetector

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrcode_scanner)

        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.viewFinder)
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, ScaleListener())
        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, GestureListener())

        viewFinder.doOnLayout {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                //TO DO
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

            val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build()

            val qrCodeAnalyzer = QRCodeImageAnalyzer(this)

            imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, qrCodeAnalyzer)

            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalysis
                )

                preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e("QRCodeScannerActivity", "Erreur lors de la liaison de l'aperçu de la caméra", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    private inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            val zoomRatio = camera?.cameraInfo?.zoomState?.value?.zoomRatio ?: 1f
            val scaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor

            val newZoomRatio = zoomRatio * scaleFactor
            camera?.cameraControl?.setZoomRatio(newZoomRatio)

            return true
        }
    }

    private inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            // Ajoutez ici la logique pour le double-tap
            return super.onDoubleTap(e)
        }
    }
}

class QRCodeImageAnalyzer(private val context: Context) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val scanner: BarcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient()

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        val rotationDegrees = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        val mediaImage = image.planes
        if (mediaImage.isNotEmpty()) {
            val buffer = mediaImage[0].buffer
            val data = ByteArray(buffer.remaining())
            buffer.get(data)

            val inputImage = InputImage.fromByteArray(
                data,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                rotationDegrees,
                InputImage.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21
            )

            scanner.process(inputImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    for (barcode in barcodes) {
                        if (barcode.valueType == Barcode.TYPE_TEXT) {
                            (context as Activity).runOnUiThread {
                                showQRCodeDetectedDialog(barcode.displayValue)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    (context as Activity).runOnUiThread {
                        showNoQRCodeRecognizedDialog()
                    }
                }
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    image.close()
                }
        } else {
            (context as Activity).runOnUiThread {
                showAnalyzerCalledDialog()
            }

        }
    }
    private fun showQRCodeDetectedDialog(qrCodeValue: String) {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("QR Code Detected: $qrCodeValue")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun showNoQRCodeRecognizedDialog() {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("No QR code recognized")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun showAnalyzerCalledDialog() {
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Analyzer called")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, if anyone has any clues it would be a great help!

Best regards

Zephyriony